# error using lando drush site:install --db-url=mysql://drupal10:drupal10@database/drupal10 -y

Tags: 10

So after I download lando I was going to start to install drupal 10 in this guide :[drupal site](https://docs.lando.dev/drupal/getting-started.html) and in the final step the download of drupal doesnt work it gives me an error when using this lando drush site:install --db-url=mysql://drupal10:drupal10@database/drupal10 -y[image]

Comment: Did you run the command with -vvv for more information?

Comment: @cilefen yes. when i used - vvv just showed all the proccess.

Comment: Maybe we would like to see that too.

Comment: @cilefen its in the image I posted